# Python - Modify dictionary from function

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, fibonacci

Okay, this question is a little strange, but I was wondering if I could do it like this.

I'm working on a simple Fibonacci number generator for fun since I was interested in programming it.
So I wrote this out:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1: return 1
    if n == 2: return 2
    else:
        return f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

and that ran very slowly, taking 15 seconds to do `f(30)` on my computer.
So then I wrote this:

```
def f(n):
    global a
    if n == 1: return 1
    if n == 2: return 1
    else:
        if "fib(%s)" % n in a:
            return a["fib(%s)" % n]
        else:
            z =  f(n-1) + f(n-2)
            a["fib(%s)" % n] = z
            return z
```

which basically stores previous results in a dictionary like so:

`{'f(1)':1,'f(2)':2,'f(3)':3,'f(4)':5}` and so on. In the function it would check if that result was in that dictionary, then just use that instead of having to redo all the calculations.

This made it tons faster. I could do `f(100)` and it instantly appear. Going by intervals of 500, I got to `f(4000)` and it was still instantaneous. The one problem was that the dictionary was getting stupidly big.

So I added `a = {}` to the end of the function, and that didn't work; it still left `a` as a massive dict.

So doing this:

```
def f(n):
    global a
    if n == 1: return 1
    if n == 2: return 1
    else:
        if "fib(%s)" % n in a:
            return a["fib(%s)" % n]
        else:
            z =  f(n-1) + f(n-2)
            a["fib(%s)" % n] = z
            return z
    a = {}
```

didn't work. but if I do this:

```
def f(n):
    global a
    if n == 1: return 1
    if n == 2: return 1
    else:
        if "fib(%s)" % n in a:
            return a["fib(%s)" % n]
        else:
            z =  f(n-1) + f(n-2)
            a["fib(%s)" % n] = z
            return z
# now run the function
f(100)
a = {}
```

`a` gets reset to an empty dictionary. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Added a={} right before return z ?

Comment: No @Skycc that doesn't work. It resets every time it runs through rendering the whole idea useless. What I want to do is reset the dictionary after the last recursion is called.

Comment: weird, its working at my side, "if "fib(%s)" % n in a:"  will call recursively, the else part will be the last recursion part, return z will exit the function already

Comment: Just a note, you may be able to shrink your dict massively by making the keys of the dictionary the Fibonacci index (n, the function argument) instead of strings. Also there's no need to do this recursively at all; something like `a, b = 0, 1; for _ in range(n): a, b = b, a+b`

Comment: Thank you @James i condensed the dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a = {}` statement inside the function was never being executed; every possible path of execution reaches a `return` before then.  If it WAS executed, you wouldn't have liked the results - it would have executed in every single recursive call to the function, meaning that your dictionary would never hold more than one item!  You would somehow have to detect the outermost call and only clear the dict there, or (much simpler) clear it outside of the recursion as in your second example.

Note that much of the size of your dictionary is coming from the strange decision to use a long string key.  Keying it with the number itself (as in `a[n] = z`) would make it much more compact.

(For future reference: the technique you've come up with here, of saving the results from previous function calls, is known as "memoization".)

Comment: Thank you! I will try that list compaction. How might I detect the outermost call?

Answer (score 0):

Despite your question, what you really want is a faster way of calculating Fibonacci sequence, right? The problem with your original approach is that recurrence, despite being very elegant and quick to code, is quite slow. Fibonacci sequence has a close form solution. You should do this math directly to speed up your code.
As convention, consider the Fibonacci sequence F(i) as: F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(k) = F(k-1) + F(k-2) k = 2, 3, ... The solution for this sequence is (I will not demonstrate it here, because is not the place for that) F(k) = (1/sqrt(5))*(a^k - b^k), where a = (1 + sqrt(5))/2 and b = (1 - sqrt(5))/2.
Thus, you code could be implemented like this:

```
def f(n):

    a = (1 + 5**.5)/2
    b = (1 - 5**.5)/2
    F = (a**n - b**n)/5**.5
    F = int(round(F)) #necessary to get an integer without the decimal part of the approximation. Afterall, you are working with irrational numbers.
    return F
```

This code scale very well for large values of n.